# Make GNOME applications dock bigger in Debian 10

Tags: debian, gnome

Is there a way to make GNOME applications dock look more like in Ubuntu, e.g. to cover the entire left side of the screen?

As I add more icons to it, it only grows to some point, after which the icons start shrinking.

[image: GNOME resize applications dock]

Debian 10 amd64, GNOME 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this extension: [dash-to-dock](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/307/dash-to-dock/)

It has a plenty of options for dock, including
the ability to extend dock to the edges.